Oracle SQL JSON_TABLE PATH references in some columns returning next record (+1?) child data elements
I am working for the first time with .JSON data stored in a Oracle DB (BLOB) column, and an having issues with getting my SQL query to render data as desired. This is also my first time using JSON_TABLE function in SQL and making data-node path references; nested or direct.
Further below is a dumbed-down version of my SQL query, and a dumbed-down version of my .json record BLOB record(s) in question reduced from 56 entries with all columns to just 3 records with example columns included.
As can be seen, parent/child-nodes of concern are primarily:

evaluation_forms [ ]

evaluations [ ]

channel_meta {}
evaluation_list [ ]

evaluation_meta {}
response {}
scores_obtained {}







All columns in my nested path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].evaluation_meta' columns reference are returning as expected, and likewise for the direct path references for anything under the channel_meta node (ex.) path '$.evaluations[*].channel_meta.teamName[0]'.
However for data under the scores_obtained node, I get null if I attempt to reference via nested path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].scores_obtained', and direct references like path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].scores_obtained.final_score[0]' are returning incorrect values, almost like off-by-one reference?
My 6/18 record for instance should return a final_score of "80" and a percent_score of "94.12", but is instead returning "70" for the direct path attempt and "82.35" for the percent_score. And the correct values for the 6/18 record seem to be returning under the 5/24 record, and so forth down the line as if off-by-x reference somehow.
Can anyone spot where I may be going wrong here? I am struggling to figure out why I am successfully referencing only the 2 of my 3 child-node properties, all of which are containers and not array objects themselves. Thanks!
JSON:
    {
  "value": {
    "page": 1,
    "size": 56,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "total_size": 56,
    "evaluation_forms": [
      {
        "template": { 
        },
        "evaluations": [
          {
            "channel_meta": {
              "teamName": [
                "Team1"
              ],
              "audioFileName": [
                "509782716366"
              ],
              "inQueueSeconds": [
                "86.824"
              ]
            },
            "evaluation_list": [
              {
                "evaluation_meta": {
                  "id": "6671a10f965337086e7829e8",
                  "evaluator_name": "Evaluator1",
                  "agent_name": "Agent1",
                  "created_at": "2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z",
                  "modified_at": "2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z",
                  "status": "SUBMITTED"
                },
                "response": {                 
                },
                "scores_obtained": {
                  "final_score": 80.0,
                  "total_points": 85.0,
                  "percent_score": 94.12,
                  "grade_assigned": "Meets Expectations"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "channel_meta": {
              "teamName": [
                "Team1"
              ],
              "audioFileName": [
                "508581330938"
              ],
              "inQueueSeconds": [
                "4.404"
              ]
            },
            "evaluation_list": [
              {
                "evaluation_meta": {
                  "id": "6650b61ebdd8b70c0af26db4",
                  "evaluator_name": "Evaluator2",
                  "agent_name": "Agent2",
                  "created_at": "2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z",
                  "modified_at": "2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z",
                  "status": "SUBMITTED"
                },
                "response": {
                },
                "scores_obtained": {
                  "final_score": 70.0,
                  "total_points": 85.0,
                  "percent_score": 82.35,
                  "grade_assigned": "Needs Work",
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "channel_meta": {
              "teamName": [
                "Team1"
              ],
              "audioFileName": [
                "508887908641"
              ],
              "inQueueSeconds": [
                "9.133"
              ]
            },
            "evaluation_list": [
              {
                "evaluation_meta": {
                  "id": "6658da061892a3009f5164b9",
                  "evaluator_name": "Evaluator2",
                  "agent_name": "Agent3",
                  "created_at": "2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z",
                  "modified_at": "2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z",
                  "status": "SUBMITTED"
                },
                "response": {
                },
                "scores_obtained": {
                  "final_score": 80.0,
                  "total_points": 85.0,
                  "percent_score": 94.12,
                  "grade_assigned": "Meets Expectations"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

SQL:
select * from (
select  
    rank () over(partition by evaluation_id order by date_loaded desc) eval_rank,
    b.evaluation_created_at,
    b.evaluation_modified_at,
    
    --debugging
    b.final_score             final_score_nested,
    b.final_score_path        final_score_path,
    b.percent_score,
    
    b.evaluation_id,
    b.evaluator_name,
    b.agent_name,
    b.evaluation_status,        
    b.teamName,
    b.audioFileName,
    b.inQueueSeconds   
from SCHEMAXYZ.TABLE_WITH_BLOB_COLUMN a
    join json_table(a.evaluation_json, '$.value.evaluation_forms[*]'  
        ERROR ON ERROR
        columns (
             template_id path '$.template.id',
             nested path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].evaluation_meta' columns (
                 evaluation_id              path '$.id', 
                 evaluator_name,
                 evaluation_agent_id        path '$.agent_id', 
                 agent_name,
                 evaluation_created_at      path '$.created_at',
                 evaluation_modified_at     path '$.modified_at',
                 evaluation_status          path '$.status'
             ),
             ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             --NOT WORKING (returns NULL)
             nested path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].scores_obtained' columns (
                final_score                 
             ),
             --NOT WORKING (returns next-level record somehow ex. 6/18 "70" instead of "80" for final score)
             final_score_path               path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].scores_obtained.final_score[0]',
             percent_score                 path '$.evaluations[*].evaluation_list[*].scores_obtained.percent_score[0]',
             ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
             teamName                       path '$.evaluations[*].channel_meta.teamName[0]',
             audioFileName                  path '$.evaluations[*].channel_meta.audioFileName[0]',
             inQueueSeconds                 path '$.evaluations[*].channel_meta.inQueueSeconds[0]'
        )
    ) b on 1=1 
) mr 
WHERE EVALUATION_ID IS NOT NULL
    AND MR.EVALUATION_STATUS NOT IN ('DELETED','NA')
    AND MR.EVAL_RANK = 1
    AND evaluation_id IN (
        '6671a10f965337086e7829e8', --6/18
        '6650b61ebdd8b70c0af26db4', --5/24 
        '6658da061892a3009f5164b9' --5/30
    )
ORDER BY evaluation_created_at DESC


You haven't given your expected output but you appear to want to use nested nested paths:
select *
from (
  select rank () over(partition by evaluation_id order by date_loaded desc) eval_rank,
         b.evaluation_created_at,
         b.evaluation_modified_at,
    
         --debugging
         b.final_score,
         b.percent_score,
    
         b.evaluation_id,
         b.evaluator_name,
         b.agent_name,
         b.evaluation_status,        
         b.teamName,
         b.audioFileName,
         b.inQueueSeconds   
  from   SCHEMAXYZ.TABLE_WITH_BLOB_COLUMN a
         CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
           a.evaluation_json,
           '$.value.evaluation_forms[*]'  
           ERROR ON ERROR
           COLUMNS (
             template_id    path '$.template.id',
             NESTED PATH '$.evaluations[*]'
             COLUMNS (
               teamName       path '$.channel_meta.teamName[0]',
               audioFileName  path '$.channel_meta.audioFileName[0]',
               inQueueSeconds path '$.channel_meta.inQueueSeconds[0]',
               NESTED PATH '$.evaluation_list[*]'
               COLUMNS (
                 evaluation_id           path '$.evaluation_meta.id', 
                 evaluator_name          path '$.evaluation_meta.evaluator_name',
                 evaluation_agent_id     path '$.evaluation_meta.agent_id', 
                 agent_name              path '$.evaluation_meta.agent_name',
                 evaluation_created_at   path '$.evaluation_meta.created_at',
                 evaluation_modified_at  path '$.evaluation_meta.modified_at',
                 evaluation_status       path '$.evaluation_meta.status',
                 final_score             path '$.scores_obtained.final_score',
                 percent_score           path '$.scores_obtained.percent_score'
              )
            )
          )
        ) b
) 
WHERE  EVALUATION_ID IS NOT NULL
AND    EVALUATION_STATUS NOT IN ('DELETED','NA')
AND    EVAL_RANK = 1
AND    evaluation_id IN (
        '6671a10f965337086e7829e8', --6/18
        '6650b61ebdd8b70c0af26db4', --5/24 
        '6658da061892a3009f5164b9' --5/30
      )
ORDER BY evaluation_created_at DESC

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE TABLE_WITH_BLOB_COLUMN (
  date_loaded DATE,
  evaluation_json BLOB CHECK (evaluation_json IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_WITH_BLOB_COLUMN (date_loaded, evaluation_json)
SELECT SYSDATE, '{
"value": {
  "page": 1,
  "size": 56,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "total_size": 56,
  "evaluation_forms": [
    {
      "template": { 
      },
      "evaluations": [
        {
          "channel_meta": {
            "teamName": [
              "Team1"
            ],
            "audioFileName": [
              "509782716366"
            ],
            "inQueueSeconds": [
              "86.824"
            ]
          },
          "evaluation_list": [
            {
              "evaluation_meta": {
                "id": "6671a10f965337086e7829e8",
                "evaluator_name": "Evaluator1",
                "agent_name": "Agent1",
                "created_at": "2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z",
                "modified_at": "2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z",
                "status": "SUBMITTED"
              },
              "response": {                 
              },
              "scores_obtained": {
                "final_score": 80.0,
                "total_points": 85.0,
                "percent_score": 94.12,
                "grade_assigned": "Meets Expectations"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "channel_meta": {
            "teamName": [
              "Team1"
            ],
            "audioFileName": [
              "508581330938"
            ],
            "inQueueSeconds": [
              "4.404"
            ]
          },
          "evaluation_list": [
            {
              "evaluation_meta": {
                "id": "6650b61ebdd8b70c0af26db4",
                "evaluator_name": "Evaluator2",
                "agent_name": "Agent2",
                "created_at": "2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z",
                "modified_at": "2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z",
                "status": "SUBMITTED"
              },
              "response": {
              },
              "scores_obtained": {
                "final_score": 70.0,
                "total_points": 85.0,
                "percent_score": 82.35,
                "grade_assigned": "Needs Work",
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "channel_meta": {
            "teamName": [
              "Team1"
            ],
            "audioFileName": [
              "508887908641"
            ],
            "inQueueSeconds": [
              "9.133"
            ]
          },
          "evaluation_list": [
            {
              "evaluation_meta": {
                "id": "6658da061892a3009f5164b9",
                "evaluator_name": "Evaluator2",
                "agent_name": "Agent3",
                "created_at": "2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z",
                "modified_at": "2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z",
                "status": "SUBMITTED"
              },
              "response": {
              },
              "scores_obtained": {
                "final_score": 80.0,
                "total_points": 85.0,
                "percent_score": 94.12,
                "grade_assigned": "Meets Expectations"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EVAL_RANK
EVALUATION_CREATED_AT
EVALUATION_MODIFIED_AT
FINAL_SCORE
PERCENT_SCORE
EVALUATION_ID
EVALUATOR_NAME
AGENT_NAME
EVALUATION_STATUS
TEAMNAME
AUDIOFILENAME
INQUEUESECONDS




1
2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z
2024-06-18T15:07:50.435Z
80
94.12
6671a10f965337086e7829e8
Evaluator1
Agent1
SUBMITTED
Team1
509782716366
86.824


1
2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z
2024-05-30T19:58:17.724Z
80
94.12
6658da061892a3009f5164b9
Evaluator2
Agent3
SUBMITTED
Team1
508887908641
9.133


1
2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z
2024-05-24T15:54:41.468Z
70
82.35
6650b61ebdd8b70c0af26db4
Evaluator2
Agent2
SUBMITTED
Team1
508581330938
4.404



fiddle

Thanks so much @MT0! Just for my own learning, why is it necessary to reference the [0] based index for the {channel_meta} data points, but nowhere else down the nested path references?

@AnalyticLunatic All the channel_meta arrays only have a single value in your sample data. If you can have multiple values in the array then maybe you do want to iterate through them but for the data you have presented you only need the first element. Also, you were using [0] to get the values in your query so I assumed that you knew why that was being used and replicated that part of your query.
